# How to create Azure Durable Functions Orchestration project using Java and Gradle?

Tags: azure, gradle, java-8, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to create Azure Durable Functions Orchestration project using Java in Visual Studio code. But it fails with the error that maven is not found in classpath. We use gradle company wide and maven is not an option.

Is there a way to create Azure Durable Functions Orchestration project using Java and gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at this moment Durable Framework is only available for C#/F#, JavaScript and Python